# crafter-cms: how to create the form using crafter

Tags: crafter-cms

I am new to crafter, I  have use the empty blueprint .and then I have created a page .but i want to design the form .How we can use the element of form like input, radio button, dropdown list, also how  to provide the action of the form ,also how to style the page , and how to use the JavaScript. Please

Answer (score 0):

Crafter CMS doesn't restrict your HTML/JS. You can use any framework/tool/markup you like.

You can edit `entry.ftl` in the `templates` folder and put whatever markup you want if you're in a hurry.

You should also read the modeling article in the docs to understand how to give power to your content authors: https://docs.craftercms.org/current/developers/content-modeling.html

If you'd like to learn how to best use Crafter CMS, consider taking a class here: https://crafteracademy.teachable.com